# Backbone js building a collection from the results returned from multiple URL's

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model that looks like this:

```
var BasicModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    a: '',
    b: '',
    c: '',
    d: '',
    e: ''
},
idAttribute: "f",
parse: function (data) {
    return data;
},
initialize: function () {
    console.log('Intialized');
},
constructor: function (attributes, options) {
    Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
}
});
```

Collections like this:

```
var BasicCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: BasicModel,
   url: urlCode
});

var ACollection = BasicCollection.extend({
   parse: function (data) {
       return data.a.b.c.d;
   }
});

var aCollection = new ACollection ();
```

And Views like this:

```
var BasicView = Backbone.View.extend({

   tagName: 'tr',

   template: _.template($('#basic-status-template').html()),

   render: function () {
       this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
       return this;
   }

});

var BasicsView = Backbone.View.extend({

   initialize: function () {
       this.render();
   },

});
```

This is how the collection fetch looks (Which builds the views):

```
aCollection.fetch({
   success: function () {

       // View

       var aView = BasicsView.extend({
           el: '#foobar #table-body',

           render: function () {
               this.$el.html('');
               aCollection.each(function (model) {
                   var x = new BasicView({
                       model: model
                   });
                   this.$el.append(x.render().el);
               }.bind(this));

               return this;
           }

       });

       var app = new aView();
   }
});
```

But now I face a problem when trying to add another piece of detail to the tables that the views will populate. One of the columns will require data that will come from a seperate url. But I still want it to be part of the same process.

Is there are way to form a collection from the result of two URL's. (i.e. a, b, d and e come from URL 1, and c comes from URL 2)?

This way all I would need to change was the template and it should all work the same. Instead of having to alter a load of other stuff as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few options:

1. Update the endpoint to send required data. This is the proper way to do it. Collection should Ideally have single endpoint
2. Send a seperate AJAX request to get data from one URL before fetching collection, then in collection's `parse` method add the data to the response fetched from collection's URL
3. Do something like:

   ```
   $.when(collection.fetch(), collection.fetchExtraData())
         .done(()=> { /* create view here */ });
   ```

   `fetchExtraData` here is a custom function that sends extra request and updates collection properly with the data. This way both requests are sent simultaneously. You need to make sure `parse` doesn't reset the data from other endpoint.